# Hapi Typescript - Controller has 'this' as undefined

Tags: typescript, hapi.js

My Hapi route calls my handler `handler: myController.get` which is defined as

```
const myController = new MyController();
```

and MyController just extends BaseController as we see below

```
export class MyController extends BaseController<MyClass> {

  constructor () {
    super(new MyDataAccess());
  }
}
```

with BaseController being

```
export class BaseController<T> {
  constructor(protected dataAccess: BaseDataAccess<T>) { }

  public async getAll(request, reply) {
    console.log('BaseController this', this);
```

Oddly enough, `this` prints out as 'undefined', which doesn't make any sense because I have already instantiated myController in the route file, which should've kicked off a new instance of BaseController for `this` to invoke, right?

**Question** How can I access an instance of MyController from a Hapi route handler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: In this case, I would bind the method to its instance. EG: `handler: myController.get.bind(myController)`

Comment: @CRice I read that post first and I it didn't seem to help my issue

Comment: @CRice Magic! (the bind that is), thanks a bunch, if you mark that as an Answer I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix I just had to .bind the controller to preserve the 'this' context

```
handler: myController.get.bind(myController)
```

Courtesy of CRice from the comments above, "In this case, I would bind the method to its instance. EG: handler: myController.get.bind(myController)" – CRice Oct 31 at 23:10